# Implementing OAuth2 with Socrata API

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, postman, socrata, soda

I'm implementing the [Socrata API](https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/ydr8-5enu.json?) to be able to parse publicly-available data from the [City of Chicago open data set](https://data.cityofchicago.org/). I am really just concerned about the data itself, so I did not initially think that I would need to implement OAuth2 through an app exposed via ngrok to be able to GET the data.

My initial attempt was to take the GET requests mentioned in their documentation and try to get responses through Postman.

Here's an example of such an attempt:

[image]

I also added my Socrata App Token as a param in the querystring, but the same message was shown.

So I tell myself, ok, maybe they deprecated GET requests without making the client go through OAuth2. If they didn't deprecate these GET requests, I would prefer not to have to deal with OAuth2, but I began implementing the authentication process and everything went successfully until I got to the following instructions found [here](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html):

[image]

I have every single value that needs to be included in that POST request except for 'authorization_type'. Where does this come from? I tried leaving 'authorization_type' in as a string, but received a response similar to the 'Invalid username or password' message in the top image in this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you only accessing public datasets from Chicago's data portal? From your screenshot it looks like you're trying to access the [Building Permits dataset](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofchicago.org/9pkb-4fbf), which is public.

Authentication is [only required for modifying datasets or accessing private data](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html), so chances are very good you don't even need to authenticate. Just include an [application token](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/app-tokens.html) with your request for throttling purposes.

Glad to help you figure out your OAuth workflow, but it sounds like it might be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Chris! I tried including 'X-App-Token': <app_token_redacted> in the header for GET https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/ydr8-5enu.json?, but I still got the authentication failure response with the same message as in the first image. Any ideas?

Comment: @AdamFreymiller - To repeat what I said above, if you're just doing `GET` requests on that public dataset, you don't need to include any `Authorization` header at all. It sounds like you're still including an unnecessary `Authorization` header, since if you were including an `X-App-Token` header with a bad app token you'd get an `Invalid app_token specified` error instead.

Comment: You're exactly right! I removed the Authorization header and it worked like a charm.